# How can I delete (or hide) the last character of the output?

Tags: c++

Here is my code. I tried to print the content of a vector with a comma after each element as the separator. How can I delete the comma after the last element then?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void printShoppingList(vector<string> s)
{
    for (auto i = s.begin(); i != s.end(); ++i)   //iterate vector from start to end
        cout<< *i<<", ";              //print each item from vector
}
```

cuz for now my output is like

```
Items: eggs, milk, sugar, chocolate, flour,
```

with a comma at the end.

Please help to delete the comma at the end of the output.

Comment: you do not want to delete it, you want not to output it

Comment: The real solution is baffling simple.

Answer (score 0):

You have access to the iterator inside the loop, so you can check that:

```
    for (auto i = s.begin(); i != s.end(); ++i) {
        cout << *i;
        if (i + 1 != s.end()) { std::cout <<", "; }
    }
```

Alternatively, you might put the comma *before* the elements (besides the first element):

```
    for (auto i = s.begin(); i != s.end(); ++i) {
        if (i != s.begin()) { std::cout <<", "; }
        cout << *i;
    }
```